# How can I ensure that a set of keys are evenly distributed across Redis cluster nodes?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I have a Redis cluster that supports a number of massive sorted sets. These sorted sets are operated on with very high frequency; a single node in the cluster can only reasonably support two sets.

For example, if I have 2 nodes and 3 sets, I can't tolerate all 3 of the sets being assigned to hash slots served by a single node.

Is there any way that I can reasonably ensure that these keys will be evenly distributed across the nodes in my cluster?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no way to ensure what you need out-of-the-box.

If you google `redis hotkeys` you can find some literature explaining the problem. Usually the "solution" they provide is not to use big sets, but in some scenarios that may not be an valid answer.

Redis provides commands to move slots from one shard to another. But if the big keys are assigned to the same slot, the problem persists.

But maybe you can play with [heys-hash-tags](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec#keys-hash-tags). It is an option provided by redis to ensure some keys to be allocated in the same slot. You can use this approach to obtain just the opposite, ensure some keys are not allocated in the same slot.

If a key contains a `{...}` pattern only that part of the key name is passed to the hash function that assigns the shard. You can try-test renaming your keys and adding for instance `bigset:1{1}`, `bigset:2{2}`, `bigset:3{3}` and find a pattern that makes each key be assigned to a different slot.